# Scale images using CSS

Tags: php, css

I'm creating a "recent blog posts" module where you can see user submitted posts, including images. My issue is that I don't want pictures to be more than 400px in height. How can i scale the image and center it?

```
<div class="feed">
  <div class="feed-image">
  <?php
  preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+)[\'"].*>/i', $row["content"], $image);
  echo '<img src="'.$image['src'].'">';
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply set the `max-height` element on the image to be `400px`

**CSS**

```
.feed-image img{
    max-height:400px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Using the `max-height` element allows for flexibility in image size, while `margin: 0 auto;` centers the image

Comment: My issue is that images takes up to much of vertical space. So I have to scale it - the width is not the problem.

Comment: I think he needs it for height, so changing to `max-height` would do it

Comment: Whoops! You're totally right. I've updated the code. This should do it now.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can just use:

```
img { 
    height: 400px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Nearly right - he wanted the height to be limited to 400, not the width.

Answer (score 0):

```
.feed-image {
  text-align: center;
}
.feed-image img {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simple.

```
img { 
max-width: 400px;
height: auto;
}
```

And for centering

```
.feed-image{
 text-align: center;
 }
```